# Sending mass emails without background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, heroku

I want to automatically send out emails to a list of users from my Rails app. 
The volume ranges from really a few users (5-10) to groups of users (50-70).
The maximum would be all users (currently 5000).

I have understood that sending emails can block the Rails app, so sending emails should be done with the help of a queueing system and a background job, e.g. by using DelayedJob, Resque or Sidekiq.

Unfortunately, having such a background job requires a worker process on the Heroku platform. And I want to avoid that due to the increased cost (at least for the beginning).

Is there any alternative approach that I could take? E.g., a second Rails app with just one worker process which only does the email handling (well I guess that would then also result in a paid worker process)?

Is it possible to send out mass emails without such a worker process via SendGrid, MailGun or any other service that integrates nicely with Heroku?

Comment: Your rails controllers have a timeout in heroku, you cant do that

Comment: Is there a way to run a worker dyno only when there is a job in the queue? I want to avoid running a worker dyno that for 99% of the time does not have anything to do. Or is this already done automatically by Heroku in that way?

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/phoet/freemium

Comment: Yes, use hire fire it adapts to your needs

Comment: I use the autoscaler gem with Sidekiq - http://rubygems.org/gems/autoscaler it starts a worker when you need it and then shuts it off again. works great.

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for the hint on hirefire (https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire). Unfortunately, the gem is not well maintained any more (seems to be due to the paid service app) and does not work with my Rails setup. However, I have found a valid and working alternative while reading hirefire's issues: workless (https://github.com/lostboy/workless). Drawback is that it works only with DelayedJob and not Resque or Sidekiq.

Comment: @John Beynon Thanks for the tip for autoscaler. I went for workless with DelayedJob for now. Works fine as well.

Comment: @phoet While the freemium setup is interesting and my original question was in this direction, I think it is also too complex to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Props to @phoet for his link

We've got a similar idea working on Heroku which we thought would be free. Turns out they billed us for the `scheduler` hours... but here's what we did:

---

**Resque**

[Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) is a queueing system which runs on Rails to queue items in Redis. It's totally recommended to [use this on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque), and is very efficient & scalable

It works like this:

> 1. Send "data" (typically ID's) to resque queue
> 2. Resque sends ID's to [Redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo)
> 3. The Resque rake job processes the Redis Queue
> 4. Perform your mailout when queue is processed (sending the email to Mandrill / SendGrid)

The reason for having a queue is as @apneadiving said - your controller will timeout AND (more importantly), your Rails app will lock up until the process has completed

There is a very good Railscast on Resque [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque):

[image]

---

**Code**

This is just basic code - can add more if you want:

```
    #app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
    def send_message
        id = params[:id]
        message = Message.find(id).broadcast!

        flash[:notice] = "Broadcast Queued!"
        redirect_to root_path
    end

   #app/models/message.rb
   def broadcast!
         self.subscribers.each do |subscriber|
             Resque.enqueue(MailoutQueue, id, subscriber.id, queue.id)
         end
   end

   #app/workers/mailout_queue.rb
   class MailoutQueue
        @queue = :mailer
        def self.perform(message_id, recipient_id, queue_id)
                MessageMailer.send_message(message_id, recipient_id).deliver
        end
   end

class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
        default from: '****************'

        def send_message(message_id, subscriber_id)

                #Declarations
                @message = Message.find(message_id)
                @subscriber = Subscriber.find(subscriber_id)

                #Send
                mail(:to => @subscriber.email, :subject => @message.title)

        end        

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations on Resque. However, I chose DelayedJob for now as I have found a solution to auto-scale worker processes on Heroku using the workless gem (https://github.com/lostboy/workless). @apneadiving suggested the hirefire gem (https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) which would also work with Resque, however, the gem itself is not maintained any more and I could not get it to work properly with my Rails setup. There is a paid service for ~10$/month/app which should actually work. I can only recommend to go for an auto-scaling solution to save costs.

Comment: No problem! You must remember that DelayedJob relies on ActiveRecord, and consequently can only process a significantly smaller number of objects than Resque. IMO, Resque & Redis are by far the most scaleable queueing solution, but if you got it working with DJ, that's also totally cool!!

Comment: I fully understand the issue that DelayedJob is slower than Resque due to the difference of Redis and ActiveRecord. If you find any solution that works to auto-scale Resque worker processes on Heroku I would be interested as well.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the reply :) I'll let you know for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here - https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid#delivering-to-multiple-recipients

This allows you to send multiple emails with only one SMTP call.